# Left alignment with makecell in a table and using textsuperscript

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, cell

I am writing a paper to an IET journal using the class **cta-author.cls**, the left alignment in a table does not work with the `\makecell` option to break line in a table cell (second column), the same thing about using `\textsuperscript` in the table (fifth column). How can I fix this problem?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{cta-author}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}{}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}{}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}{}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}


\begin{document}
 \begin{table*}[!t]
        \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
        \processtable{A Comparative Description of Different Algorithms\label{table3}}
{\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{2.24cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{2.74cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{1.74cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{1.74cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{4.74cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{2.74cm}}
\toprule
Authors & Feature extraction & Feature reduction & Fusion level & Database and number of image considered & Evaluation results (best EER) \\
\midrule
Y. Wang et al. \cite{16} 2003 2 & {\makecell{Face: PCA and FDA \\ Iris: 2D Gabor}} & $/$ & Score level fusion & NLPR$^{LAD}$ for iris good quality. ORL, MIT and Yale for face. 90 subjects with 5 face  and 5 iris images for each subject & EER = 0 \% \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}{}
\end{table*}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try using `\makecell[l]{...}`? Another possibility without the makecell package would be using `\newline` for the linebreak in a table cell. Additionally, I can't see any problem in using `\textsuperscript`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert a linebreak in a `m` type cell, you can use the `\newline` command as in the following example.

```
\documentclass{cta-author}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
 \begin{table*}[!t]
        \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
        \processtable{
        A Comparative Description of Different Algorithms\label{table3}}
{\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{2.24cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{2.74cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{1.74cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{1.74cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{4.74cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{2.74cm}}
\toprule
Authors & Feature extraction & Feature reduction & Fusion level & Database and number of image considered & Evaluation results (best EER) \\
\midrule
Y. Wang et al. \cite{16} 2003 2 & Face: PCA and FDA \newline Iris: 2D Gabor & $/$ & Score level fusion & NLPR\textsuperscript{LAD} for iris good quality. ORL, MIT and Yale for face. 90 subjects with 5 face  and 5 iris images for each subject & EER = 0 \% \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}{}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

If you prefer the `makecell` package, you should explicitly specify the horizontal alignment, in your case by using `\makecell[l]{<text>}`.